# nodejs readers/writers concurrency

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, promise, deadlock, q

Here's some simple code that demonstrates what I'm trying to do

```
myVar = 1
reader = () ->
    getDataFromServer1().then ->
        # uses myVar and does stuff according to its value
    # returns promise
writer = () ->
    getDataFromServer2().then ->
        # assigns to myVar
    # returns promise

Q.all([reader(), reader(), reader(), writer(), writer(), writer()]).done ->
    console.log 'done'
```

So I have multiple threads running at the same time. some of them change the value of `myVar` and some read the value and rely on it. And I don't want a writer to write while another writer is writing or a reader is reading. Readers can read at the same time though. This is similar to the [Readers–writers problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem).

I tried to solve this by defining a `sharedResource` function as follows

```
sharedResource = (initialValue) ->
    readLock = Q.fcall ->
    writeLock = Q.fcall ->

    value: initialValue
    read: (action) ->
        newPromise = writeLock.then action
        readLock = Q.all([newPromise, readLock]).then -> null
        newPromise
    write: (action) ->
        newPromise = Q.all([readLock, writeLock]).then action
        writeLock = Q.all([newPromise, writeLock]).then -> null
        newPromise
```

and then changed my code to use it

```
myVar = sharedResource 1
reader = () ->
    myVar.read ->
        # noone is writing to myVar while doing this request:
        getDataFromServer1().then (data) -> 
            # read myVar.value instead of myVar, e.g.
            expect(data == myVar.value)
writer = () ->
    myVar.write ->
        # noone reads or writes myVar while doing this request:
        getDataFromServer2().then (data) ->
            # change myVar.value instead of myVar, e.g.
            myVar.value = data

Q.all([reader(), reader(), reader(), writer(), writer(), writer()]).done ->
    console.log 'done'
```

This worked perfectly when I had only one `sharedResource`. Here's where the problem occurs

```
myVar1 = sharedResource 1
myVar2 = sharedResource 2
action1 = () ->
    myVar1.read ->
        myVar2.write ->
            getDataFromServer1().then (data) ->
                myVar2.value = data + myVar1.value
action2 = () ->
    myVar2.read ->
        myvar1.write ->
            getDataFromServer2().then (data) ->
                myVar1.value = data + myVar2.value

Q.all([action1(), action1(), action1(), action2(), action2(), action2()]).done ->
    console.log 'done'
```

Here a case of [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) happens. Each promise is waiting for the other one to resolve. None of them get resolved and the program stops.

**Edit**

I'll try my best to explain:

This is actually code to test my server. To see how it performs when multiple clients send multiple requests at the same time. Say for example every time `action1` sends a request, the server increments a value stored in it's database. On the client side (the code that you are seeing) I also increment a variable which contains the value I expect to be on the server. And then when `action2` sends a request, the server responds with that value and I `assert` the value in the response to be the same as my local variable.

So I have to get the lock before I send a request to make sure `action2` doesn't ask for the variable while it is being changed.

I hope that helps.

Comment: I've actually talked about readers-writers with kriskowal the other day! Lemme dig it up. Inb4 https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thank you so much. I will be really appreciative if I get an answer.

Comment: Um, why do you get the locks even before fetching the data from the server? Are your read-write actions (in the callback after the data is fetched) actually asynchronous? That doesn't get clear from your example.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for your observation. I didn't think anyone would even bother to read my long code. I edited the question and added some clarification.

Comment: Hm, I don't think introducing the server and multiple clients makes this any clearer… Rather, you should introduce variables in your code that are sent to the server, and parameters in your callbacks for the server results…

Comment: @Bergi I think posting my complete code would just confuse people.

Comment: No, but you need to show the data flow through your promises. If you don't know what I mean, you could still *link* the complete code (and I'll try to understand your problem)

Comment: @Bergi I think my code needs a lot of refactoring. But here you go https://gist.github.com/alidorosty/852e257dbb38e8f55a0f

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand your situation better now. I've also edited your question as I hope this helps better to understand your `sharedRessource` design (I initially had problems with those `action`s, expecting them to get the current value as a parameter and return a (promise for) the value to be written; instead of that `.value` manipulation). Can you confirm it still conveys your intention?

Comment: I see you got no answer yet and Kris probably didn't have time. Are you still interested in an answer?

Comment: @adm Sorry, but I miss something. JavaScript is concurrent but not parallel: each function invocation is atomic, i.e. `then(read_is_atomic())`. The only nasty thing with your code is that response doesn't always immediately follows the request made, it may be hindered somewhere and arrive later.